# setting default value to missing properties in model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, default

Suppose we have directive myDirective:

```
function myDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: template,
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {},
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {

            }
        }
    }
```

It usses ng-model directive. And suppose we use this directive:

```
// myAppController
scope.myDirectiveData = {age: 10};


// templates

<form>
    <div ng-controller="myAppController">
        <my-directive ng-model="myDirectiveData"></my-directive>
    </div>
</form>
```

myDirective model must contain age and sex properties. But as you can see in our case we have only age property in model. In such cases when model does not have some properties or whole model is undefined I want to set default value to model, that is:

```
link: function postLink(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
    var defaultModelValue = {age: 20, sex: 'female'};

    // modelValue variable is not defined somewhere, I just wrote it for example what I want to do
    if (!modelValue) {
        // modelValue = defaultModelValue;
    }

    if (angular.isUndefined(modelValue.age)) {
        // modelValue.age = defaultModelValue.age;
    }

    if (angular.isUndefined(modelValue.sex)) {
        // modelValue.sex = defaultModelValue.sex;
    }
}
```

How can I set default values to missing properties in model?

I could use $setViewValue to set default values to missing properties in model but in this case my control becomes dirty. I could use in this case $setPristine, but all what I described now seems strange and bad to me. Maybe there is a good solution
or best practice for this issue(setting default values to missing properties in model during directive initialization)?

Comment: Vanilla, you can create an _Object_ with default values via `var objWithDefaults = Object.assign({}, objOfDefaults, inputObject);`. The first arg is the reference to be used as the base, so if you want this to use the same ref as `inputObject` then assign it back onto it after (a second step to avoid weird behaviour) `Object.assign(inputObject, objWithDefaults);`

Comment: But if modelValue is string, and it is empty, and I want to set default string, what should I do in this case?

Comment: And maybe model must be object, but we got undefined, so I want to set default object to model, what should I do in this case?